# How can I change the volume of my discord bot in discord.js V13?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, volume

I am creating a Discord Bot and I am getting along quite good, however, I am now trying to implement a command for changing the volume of the bot and I can't figure out how to do it. All I am finding on the Internet is for V12 or below, but I am using the new version of discord.js - V13. Here is what I have for playing the music:

```js
const connection = await connect(channel);
const audioPlayer = createAudioPlayer();

const stream = createStream(song.url);
const resource = createAudioResource(stream, {
  inputType: StreamType.Arbitrary,
});

stream.on('error', () => playQueue(guild, channel));

connection.subscribe(audioPlayer);
audioPlayer.play(resource);
```

This all works but does one of you know how to change the volume?

*Side question:*
*I am also trying to make a `/seek <time>` to jump to any place in the video and neither am I making any progress with that.*

Comment: resource.volume = 30 for example doesn't work?

Comment: resoure.volume is a read-only property so I cant change it, I tried that already; maybe though this is just a typescript thing

Comment: resource.volume.setVolume(2) too? (according to https://amishshah.github.io/prism-media/?api#core.VolumeTransformer#setVolume)

Comment: "1 is normal, 0.5 is half, 2 is double."

Comment: Now I don't get any errors anymore, which is good, but it doesn't do anything. When I try  to use `inlineVolume: true` when I create my audioResource, it throws an error saying `Cannot find module '@discordjs/opus`. Do I have to install that?

Comment: You should yes.

Comment: Now it works, thank you :)

Comment: For seek I found this https://githubmemory.com/repo/DevSnowflake/discord-ytdl-core/issues/17

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it now, thanks to Leau:

The problem I had was that I was trying to set `resource.volume` to the value, whereas I actually would have had to do it via `resource.volume.setVolume()` with the @discordjs/opus package installed and the option on resource for `inlineVolume` set to true